# Norm of the projection of an orthonormal basis onto one dimensional subpace in $\mathbb R^n$

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products, projection

Let $\{x_1, \dots, x_n\}$ be an orthonormal set of $\mathbb R^n$. Let $V$ be an arbitrary one-dimensional subspace. I am trying to determine the quantity
\begin{align*}
\sum_{j=1}^n \langle P_V(x_j), P_V(x_j) \rangle,
\end{align*}
where $P_V(x_j)$ denotes the orthogonal projection onto $V$.

Here is my strategy: Let $v \in V$ be a unit vector. We note
\begin{align*}
\langle P_V(x_j), P_V(x_j) \rangle = \langle (\langle x_j, v\rangle v),  (\langle x_j, v\rangle v) \rangle = |\langle x_j, v \rangle |^2.
\end{align*}
So 
\begin{align*}
\sum_1^n\langle P_V(x_j), P_V(x_j) \rangle = \sum_1^n |\langle x_j, v \rangle |^2 = \|v\|_2^2 = 1.
\end{align*}
Is this correct?

Comment: In think you meant to write $u_j$ instead of $x_j$. Other than that your answer is correct.

Comment: Other fun question: Suppose that $\langle P_V(x_j), P_V(x_j) \rangle= \langle P_V(x_i), P_V(x_i) \rangle$ for all $i,j$, does this uniquely define the line $V$?

Comment: I think $V$ is necessarily the line containing $\sum_i x_i$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy: Are you suggesting this is not right? If so, could you give a right idea?

Comment: @user9527 I believe Kavi Rama Murthy answered the question of Mathematician 42.

Comment: @PaulFrost: Thanks. I misunderstood it.

Comment: @Mathematician42: Should the reasoning be: Pick an unit vector $ v \in V$, then $\langle P_V(x_j), P_V(x_j) \rangle = \langle P_V(x_i), P_V(x_i) \rangle \implies |\langle x_j, v \rangle|^2 = |\langle x_i, v\rangle|^2$. We write $v = \sum_i^n \langle x_i, v \rangle v$. But then the line is not unique because we can choosing different sign in the sum. Thanks.

Comment: You can always try to solve the second question and post it as a new question on this site. It's against the policy of the site to use this question to solve another one here